# Is it possible to have git submodule urls point to subfolders of a repository?

Tags: git

Given the project A and B:

```
. A
- pom.xml
- src
-- main
--- resources
---- soapui-suite
--- foo-A
- foo-A

. B
- pom.xml
- src
-- main
--- resources
---- soapui-suite
--- foo-B
- bar-B
```

Now I'd like the directory `soapui-suite` of module A to be a submodule of module B. In other words: `B/src/main/resources/soapui-suite` should point to `A/src/main/resources/soapui-suite/`.

Is this possible?

I know I could add the whole module A as a submodule of B with this command:

```
git submodule add -f ssh://A.git ./src/main/resources/soapui-suite
```

but this would result in a duplicate filestructure like

```
B/src/main/resources/soapui-suite/src/main/resources/soapui-suite/
```

which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git operates on entire repositories, not on individual subdirectories.  You cannot add a *subdirectory* of a repository as a submodule.  Your options are really:

1. just add the the submodule and live with the extra path components, or
2. add the submodule and then create symlinks to create the path structure you want.

Or, 3, I guess, reorganize the submodule repository to better fit your needs.